# How to set default value for regular in Promtail configueration

Tags: promtail

I have Docker swarm of 3 nodes where are running monitoring apps (exporters, grafana, etc..) per evironment (dev, stg and prd). **Dev** an **stg** containers contains `_<env>_` in their container name, so for **dev** its `_dev_` and for **stg** its `_stg_`. Prd containers does not have environment contained in the name of container.

I am parsing with regular expression from the name the environment and setting it up as label:

```
  relabel_configs:
    ...
    - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
      regex: '/.*_(dev|stg)_.*'
      target_label: 'env'
```

I would like to set **prd** as default environment. I tried to set it as `static_label`:

```
  pipeline_stages:
    - static_labels:
        env: prd
```

But then, all containers has **env** label set to **prd**. It looks like relabel config is used first and then static labels are applied. Is there a way how to configure it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, its looks like `relabel_configs` is executed before `pipeline_stages`. So firstly, I parsed **dev** or **stg** from container name with this configuration:

```yaml
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
    regex: '/.*_(dev|stg)_.*'
    target_label: 'env'
```

And than, using template stage with go template if condition check, if label `env` exists, keep it. If not, create it with default value **prd**:

```yaml
pipeline_stages:
  - template:
      source: env
      template: '{{ if .Value }}{{ .Value }}{{ else }}prd{{ end }}'
  - labels:
      env:
```

Also important section is `labels`. Stage **template** will only create key **env** with value **prd** (if does not exists from previous step), but does not create label from it. Thats why there have to be this **labels** stage (label stage create labels from keys in the message).

This is my final pipeline:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: docker
  docker_sd_configs:
  - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    refresh_interval: 30s
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
      regex: '/.*\.([0-9]{1,2})\..*'
      target_label: 'replica'
    - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name']
      regex: '(.*)'
      target_label: 'service'
    - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_label_com_docker_stack_namespace']
      regex: '(.*)'
      target_label: 'stack'
    - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
      regex: '/.*_(dev|stg)_.*'
      target_label: 'env'
  pipeline_stages:
    - template:
        source: env
        template: '{{ if .Value }}{{ .Value }}{{ else }}prd{{ end }}'
    - labels:
        env:
    - static_labels:
        hostname: ${NODE_HOSTNAME}
```

Variable `NODE_HOSTNAME` is passed to the container from node where container is running on. So Its hostname one of node name from swarm.